# JPA avoiding multiple subquery

Tags: java, jpa

I need a little help setting up my query.  I don't want to have to make multiple selects to form basically the same sub-query if I can avoid it.  In a nut shell, I have Objects called `TimeSlot` that are used to track several details.  Those `TimeSlot`'s are items that are paid on.  When its time for the `TimeSlot` to submit for a reimbursement they are used to create a `PayableTimeSlot`.  Before the `TimeSlot` can be paid I need to make sure it has not been paid already.

As it sits the following is my query:

```
@NamedQuery(
   name = "TimeSlot.by.person.academy.id.by.contract.date",
   query = "select distinct ts 
       from TimeSlot ts 
       join ts.invitedInstructors ii 
       join ts.academyClass ac 
       join ac.academy a 
       where ii.person.id = ? 
       and a.id = ? 
       and ts.schedule.startDateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?  
       and ts.id not in (select e.id from PayableTimeslot pts join pts.event e)
       and ? not in (select e.claimant from PayableTimeslot pts join pts.event e)")
```

As you can see I am already selecting an element from the PayableTimeSot for the first `not in`.  Is there a way to expand the sub-query into:
`(select e.id, e.claimant from PayableTimeslot pts join pts.event e)`  I am just not sure how to check for multiple items `not in` the sub-query.  By all means if there is a better attack of the problem than the way I am doing it let me know.

Unless you all think the multiple selects wont be a big deal...  There will be on average 30-50 entry's a week into the table with each entry being copied (for an audit trail) upwards of 7-9 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some thinking this is what I came up with.  I was indeed trying to answer the problem in the wrong way...  I was doing two sub querys when all I needed was a where on the first thus combining the two.

```
@NamedQuery(
   name = "TimeSlot.by.person.academy.id.by.contract.date",
   query = "select distinct ts "
   + "from TimeSlot ts "
   + "join ts.invitedInstructors ii "
   + "join ts.academyClass ac "
   + "join ac.academy a "
   + "where ii.person.id = ? "
   + "and a.id = ? "
   + "and ts.schedule.startDateTime BETWEEN ? AND ?  "
   + "and ts.id not in (select e.id from PayableTimeslot pts join pts.event e where pts.claimant = ?)")
```